# Scipy solves eigenproblem of a matrix incorrectly

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

I am facing a very weird behaviour of SciPy when solving eigenproblem of a singular matrix, namely the computed eigenvalues are incorrect if I generate the matrix by some functions (matrix `der` in the code below). However, if I manually type the matrix in (`der2`) the diagonalisation seems to yield proper results. This can be also checked by subtracting both matrices, which is all done in the code below.

the code is

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.linalg import eigvals

def cbar(k, n):
    """
    cbar function for coefficients
    """
    if k==0 or k==n-1:
        return np.float128(2.)
    else:
        return np.float128(1.)    

def ChebCollDer(x):
    """
    ChebCollDer  Chebyshev collocation differentiation matrix.
    """
    xx=np.array(x)  
    n=xx.size
    d=np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            if i!=k:
                d[i,k]=cbar(i, n)*np.float128(sp.power(-1., i+k))/(xx[i]-xx[k])/cbar(k,n)
    for i in range(n):
        tmp=-sp.sum(d[i,:])
        d[i,i]=tmp

    return d
nn=5
xx=(np.cos(sp.pi*np.linspace(0,1.0,nn)))/2.
der=ChebCollDer(xx)
print eigvals(der)
der2=[[ 11.0 ,-13.656854,  4.0 ,-2.3431458 , 1.0],
 [ 3.4142136, -1.4142136, -2.8284271,  1.4142136, -0.58578644],
 [-1.0,  2.8284271,  1.110223e-16, -2.8284271,  1.0]
 ,[0.58578644, -1.4142136,  2.8284271,  1.4142136, -3.4142136],
 [-1.0,2.3431458,-4.0 ,13.656854,-11.0]]
print eigvals(der2)

print der-der2
```

and the results are:
eigenvalues of matrix `der`:

```
[ 0.00389434+0.00282825j  0.00389434-0.00282825j -0.00148641+0.00457958j -0.00148641-0.00457958j -0.00481586+0.j        ]
```

eigenvalues of `der2`:

```
[  9.71161644e-02+0.j          -9.71161490e-02+0.j          -3.08158279e-08+0.j 7.69629619e-09+0.09711159j   7.69629619e-09-0.09711159j]
```

see that `der2` has one eigenvalue that is numerically zero, as should be since the matrix `der` has a null eigenvector which is simply `[1,1,1,1,1]`
The biggest element of `der-der2` is of order 10E-08.
I suspect, that there is some type conversion problem, but have no idea where it comes from.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a full answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

You might have more luck posting on the math page since I think this is a numerical analysis problem.

If I do `s,v = sp.linalg.eig(der)` then all the `u` seem to satisfy the eignevalue equation in the sense that `der@u - s*u` is close to zero.

Another interesting thing is that the eigenvalues of `der` all have equal modulus, and are are have arguments equally spaced around the circle of this radius. Like scaled 5-th roots of -1.

In fact, if you take and equally weighted linear combination of the eigenvectors from the scipy output (i.e. right multiply `v` by the all ones vector) you will get close to a constant vector corresponding to the zero eigenvalue.

That said, I'm not very sure what is going on.

Also, your function `ChebCollDer` will output a regular ndarray of `float` instead of `float128` since you do not initialize it at `float128`. That means that even though you do some calculations in `float128`, they get cast to the default scipy float before they are stored in `d`.